# I have a problem adding a new shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, code

I'm trying to add a new shipping method, i create the module in the `etc` directory like `Mrsolutions_Domesa.xml`, inside is the next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mrsolutions_Domesa>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </Mrsolutions_Domesa>
</modules>
</config>
```

I created my directories tree in `app/code/local`.

`local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/etc/config.xml`

`local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/etc/config.xml`

`local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/Module/Carrier.php`

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mrsolutions_Domesa>
        <module>0.0.1</module>
    </Mrsolutions_Domesa>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mrsolutions_domesa>
            <class>Mrsolutions_Domesa_Model</class>
        </mrsolutions_domesa>
    </models>
</global>
<default>
    <carriers>
        <mrsolutions_domesa>
            <active>1</active>
            <model>mrsolutions_domesa/carrier</model>
            <title>Domesa</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
        </mrsolutions_domesa>
    </carriers>
</default>
</config>
```

system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <carriers translate="label" module="shipping">
        <groups>
            <mrsolutions_domesa translate="label">
                <label>Domesa</label>
                <frontend_type>Domesa</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <active translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </active>
                    <title translate="label">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </title>
                    <sort_order translate="label">
                        <label>Sort Order</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </sort_order>
                    <sallowspecific translate="label">
                        <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </sallowspecific>
                    <specificcountry translate="label">
                        <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                    </specificcountry>
                </fields>
            </mrsolutions_domesa>
        </groups>
    </carriers>
</sections>
</config>
```

Carrier.php:

```
class Mrsolutions_Domesa_Model_Carrier
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
protected $_code = 'mrsolutions_domesa';

public function collectRates(
    Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
)
{
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $result->append($this->_getStandardShippingRate());
    return $result;
}

protected function _getStandardShippingRate()
{
    $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
    $rate->setMethod('standand');
    $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard');
    $rate->setPrice(123);
    $rate->setCost(0);
    return $rate;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array(
        'standard' => 'Standard',
    );
}
}
```

My shipping method no appear in `System → Configuration → Shipping Method`

Comment: did you flush the cache, log out and back in? also in your first step, I'm assuming you meant for the `Mrsolutions_Domesa.xml` file to go into the `app/etc/modules` directory?

Comment: also `local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/Module/Carrier.php` should be `local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/Model/Carrier.php`

Comment: i did it, but nothing yet. I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Sorry yes, is `Model` and is fine in my directory, but nothing yet.

Comment: I recreated your module and it worked right away - you obviously have a typo in one of your file paths or didn't clear cache

Comment: Can you send me your module?

Comment: Your directory is the same?

Comment: see my answer with the code and paths that worked

Comment: yes, i did it (flush the config cache)

Answer (score 0):

`/app/code/local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/Model/Carrier.php`

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: info
     * Date: 10/30/2018
     * Time: 4:05 PM
     */

    class Mrsolutions_Domesa_Model_Carrier
        extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
        implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
    {
        protected $_code = 'mrsolutions_domesa';

        public function collectRates(
            Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
        )
        {
            $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
            $result->append($this->_getStandardShippingRate());
            return $result;
        }

        protected function _getStandardShippingRate()
        {
            $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $rate->setMethod('standand');
            $rate->setMethodTitle('Standard');
            $rate->setPrice(123);
            $rate->setCost(0);
            return $rate;
        }

        public function getAllowedMethods()
        {
            return array(
                'standard' => 'Standard',
            );
        }
    }
```

`app/code/local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mrsolutions_Domesa>
                <module>0.0.1</module>
            </Mrsolutions_Domesa>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <mrsolutions_domesa>
                    <class>Mrsolutions_Domesa_Model</class>
                </mrsolutions_domesa>
            </models>
        </global>
        <default>
            <carriers>
                <mrsolutions_domesa>
                    <active>1</active>
                    <model>mrsolutions_domesa/carrier</model>
                    <title>Domesa</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                </mrsolutions_domesa>
            </carriers>
        </default>
    </config>
```

`/app/code/local/Mrsolutions/Domesa/etc/system.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <sections>
            <carriers translate="label" module="shipping">
                <groups>
                    <mrsolutions_domesa translate="label">
                        <label>Domesa</label>
                        <frontend_type>Domesa</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <fields>
                            <active translate="label">
                                <label>Enabled</label>
                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            </active>
                            <title translate="label">
                                <label>Title</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            </title>
                            <sort_order translate="label">
                                <label>Sort Order</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            </sort_order>
                            <sallowspecific translate="label">
                                <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                                <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            </sallowspecific>
                            <specificcountry translate="label">
                                <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                                <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                            </specificcountry>
                        </fields>
                    </mrsolutions_domesa>
                </groups>
            </carriers>
        </sections>
    </config>
```

`app/etc/modules/Mrsolutions_Domesa.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mrsolutions_Domesa>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends>
                    <Mage_Shipping />
                </depends>
            </Mrsolutions_Domesa>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

[image]

Comment: You have the `compilation` enabled?

Comment: no - never enable it when developping

Comment: exactly! It is disabled at this time, but nothing yet. Your code is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: are your file names and path the same?

Comment: Yes, are the same

Comment: one more crazy possibility - did you by any chance previously disable this module from the admin system=>configuration=>advanced>?

Comment: do you have some other type of caching?

Comment: No, and I deleted the contents of the `cache` and `session` directories.

Comment: let me suggest something else. can you break the markup of the config.xml file? if that file is getting hit and the markup is broken your site will throw an error right away

Comment: Well, I broke my `config.xml` and nothing happened

Comment: and you flushed config cache?

Comment: your permissions are correct on your server?

Comment: I'm work in a localhost

Comment: I don't know what to tell you

Comment: Can you try going to system config and changing the default store name for example and then save the config?

Comment: ok, now the shpping method is showing in client side, but not in magento panel

Comment: after you saved the config in admin?

Comment: Thanks Haim, I solved by modifying the `system.xml` file

Comment: What did you modify?